# Can't add htmlAttribute to Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to use jQuery to do some validation on a DropDownList. Therefore I am trying to add a `htmlAttribute` like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("category_id", "Vælg..", new { @class = "required" })
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error   2   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MvcApplication3.Models.Question>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>, string)' has some invalid arguments   c:\Users\Kenan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication3 - Copy\MvcApplication3\Views\AdminQuestion\GridQuestion.cshtml 38  14  MvcApplication3
Error   3   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' c:\Users\Kenan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication3 - Copy\MvcApplication3\Views\AdminQuestion\GridQuestion.cshtml 38  47  MvcApplication3
Error   4   Argument 4: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'string'   c:\Users\Kenan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication3 - Copy\MvcApplication3\Views\AdminQuestion\GridQuestion.cshtml 38  57  MvcApplication3
```

If I change the code to:

```
@Html.DropDownList("category_id", null, new { @class = "required " })
```

It works, but without a default value, which is not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice in the [Overload List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx) that there's no overload for `string, string, object`.

The overload you may be looking for is:

```
DropDownList(HtmlHelper, String, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, Object)
```

You'd write this in your view as:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SomeString", MyEnumerable, new {@class = "required"}
```

The reason your second example works, i.e. `string, null, object` is because `IEnumerable<T>` is nullable.

**UPDATE**

You may find that `DropDownListFor` is a better match for what you need.

The exact overload you'll probably want is:

```
HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, Object
```

implimented as:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.category_id, ViewBag.category_id, new {@class = "required"})
```

Comment: What should i write in the HtmlHelper parameter?

Comment: That's already covered by the @Html bit you're using. It's the same as other extension methods where the first parameter is specificed as (this HtmlHelper,...). So you can ignore that parameter knowing it's covered by your @Html part.

Comment: I am getting the SelectList from the ViewBag. It is called ViewBag.category_id - I have changed the code to this: @Html.DropDownList("Kategorier", ViewBag.category_id, new { @class = "required" } ) but i am getting this error:

Comment: Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MvcApplication3.Models.Question>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax. c:\Users\Kenan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication3 - Copy\MvcApplication3\Views\AdminQuestion\GridQuestion.cshtml 38 10 MvcApplication3

Comment: What is category_id ??? If it's an int, there's no overload for string, int, object. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes sorry for being unclear. category_id is this: ViewBag.category_id = new SelectList(db.Category, "category_id", "category_name");

Comment: Given that SelectList accepts an IEnumerable, why not pass that IEnumerable straight to your DropDownList via the ViewBag instead of converting it to a SelectList?

Comment: By the looks of it, db.Category is an IEnumerable. Pass that to your DropDownList as the IEnumerable parameter and everything should work as expected.

Comment: and I suggest using a ViewModel rather than putting things in the ViewBag. That's my preference anyway. Makes everything seem a bit neater and more managable.

Comment: This was auto-created by the MVC framework in the "Create" view. Also, creating the SelectList beforehand tells it the value and the text it should use. The error is the same if i change it to ViewBag.category_id = db.Category; - thanks for being patient btw :)

Comment: I had to cast the ViewBag.category_id to (SelectList) ViewBag.category_id - Thanks for the help ! :)

Comment: Let me just update my answer. I think DropDownListFor will be a better suit for your needs.